# Why are my PHP bitwise comparisons not producing what I expect?

Tags: php, comparison

I have the following code:

```
foreach(str_split('abcd') as $char) {
    $total += ($char & 1);
}
echo $total;
```

It outputs `0`. However, I would expect it to output `2`, because `a` and `c` in their ASCII binary representations are odd numbers (97 and 99 I believe).

It seems that regardless of what I pass to `str_split`, I always end up with `0`. Why is this, and how can I successfully count the bytes in a string that have the first bit set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grab the ASCII code first, Your code doesn't do it.

```
<?php
foreach(str_split('abcd') as $char) {
    $char=ord($char);  //Missed this?
    $total += ($char & 1);
}
echo $total;  // Outputs 2

?>
```

Comment: Hmm, well I guess that makes sense, thanks. I assumed that getting the integer value first was redundant, but that must not be the case.

I've got it working now, thanks, although I used `hexdec(bin2hex($char))` instead of `ord($char)`, to allow for multibyte characters (I simplified the example in my question).